# Dropdown menu not toggling and resembling like button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am creating a bootstrap dropdown menu dynamically. Initially, it is looking like dropdown menu but after first click, it visibly gets changed to button while works like dropdown menu, i.e on button click I can see dropdown options. Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="dropdown" id="ApplicationNames" style="visibility: hidden">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Application
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="Appdropdown"></ul>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery.

```
 $('.dropdown-menu-left a').click(function () {
    var dropdownMenuItems = "School,College";
    var arrdropdownMenuItems = dropdownMenuItems.split(',');
    var dropdownMenuhtml = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < arrdropdownMenuItems.length; i++) {
        dropdownMenuhtml += '<li><a href="#">' + arrdropdownMenuItems[i] + '</a></li>';
    }
    $('#ApplicationNames').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#Appdropdown').append(dropdownMenuhtml);
});
```

What is being missed here to display the dropdown instead of button after being selected. Please help.
[image: Dropdown]
[image: Button]

Comment: You've tagged the question with CSS, but not added any CSS to your question. It's probably going to be useful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @Kyle I have not used any inline css. Bootstrap CSS Classes has been used. So I tagged CSS. Thanks !

Comment: Can you give us a snippet for your issue?

Comment: @Samir I have added the images. Please have a look

Comment: I think your down arrow is getting erased after first click, correct?

Comment: @Samir Yes. Correct

Answer (score 2):

```js
  $('.dropdown-menu-left a').click(function () {
var dropdownMenuItems = "School,College";
var arrdropdownMenuItems = dropdownMenuItems.split(',');
var dropdownMenuhtml = ''
for (var i = 0; i < arrdropdownMenuItems.length; i++) {
 dropdownMenuhtml += '<a href="#">' + arrdropdownMenuItems[i] + '</a>';
}
console.log(dropdownMenuhtml);
$('#ApplicationNames').css("visibility", "visible");
 
if($('#Appdropdown').html() == ""){
 $('#Appdropdown').html(dropdownMenuhtml);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown-menu-left"><a href="#">Click me</a>
 
<div class="btn-group" id="ApplicationNames" style="visibility: hidden">
  <button type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="Appdropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check for the arrow styling. It is directly coming from the css.

Comment: Can, you please update your, complete HTML and css for that particularly for button?

Comment: Arrow is coming now, but I am seeing double double arrow for all the dropdowns available in ,my page. Is there any way we can do it from CSS Class adding using jquery instead of inline CSS

Comment: @Lara, i have added the snippet, please check.

Comment: @Lara, instead of, `<ul>`, i have used the `<div>`. You can use `<ul>` as well.

Comment: but I am seeing double double arrow for all the dropdowns available in ,my page. Is there any way we can do it from CSS Class adding using jquery instead of inline CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128430/discussion-between-samir-and-lara).